# Can an arbitrary vector space $V$ over a field $F$ be turned into an algebra over $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I proved that every associative algebra with multiplication $\ast$ turn into a Lie algebra by a Lie bracket derived from $\ast$.

$\textbf{ My question:}$

Can an arbitrary vector space $V$ over a field $F$ be turned into an algebra over $F$ (associative or nonassociative algebra) by defining a nontrivial bilinear map $\ast\colon V\times V\rightarrow V$ as a product?

If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: The answer is yes. You may just define any product on a basis of $V$, e.g., $ e_i.e_j=e_1$.

Comment: What about a pointwise multiplication in a fixed basis? Existence of such basis may require AC though iirc

Comment: @Burde. Thanks. To anybody: l don't understand why down vote for the question. What is the problem? First, I know that my question may be trivial and easy. Second, How is for vector spaces with uncountable basis? Anyway, I think that the product must be independent of basis. Is it true ?

Comment: The product tule must be independent from the basis, but fixing the basis to introduce one is not a problem. What’s the confusion in case of uncountable basis?

Comment: @SBF. Thanks. Probably, There is no problem. But I want know that practically how do you define a bilinear product in an arbitrary vector space $V$ over a field $F$ that $V$ be turned into an algebra over $F$ ?

Answer (score 2):

To define an algebra on $V$ with basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$, you need structure constants
$$
e_ie_j=\sum_k\Gamma_{ij}^ke_k
$$
that satsify a few axioms (e.g. for associativity or commutativity), then extend everything linearly.

One can come up with examples off the top of one's head, e.g. $e_ie_j=\delta_{ij}e_i$ which is the "coordinate-wise" algebra on $V\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}Ke_i$ if the base field is $K$.  However, this isn't an algebra over $K$ if $V$ is infinite dimensional (the infinite sum $1=\sum_ie_i$ that you would want doesn't exist without defining some topology).  I believe you can fix this by "reserving" some basis element $e_0$ to act as the identity $e_0e_i=e_ie_0=e_i$.

If you don't care about it being an "algebra" in the sense that there's a map $K\hookrightarrow V$, then the zero product or the product defined by $e_ie_j=\delta_{i,j}e_i$ is bilinear (and associative and commutative).

In functional analysis, when an identity doesn't exist, one can be adjoined or the algebra can be enlarged.  For instance, the space of compactly supported continuous functions $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ can be embedded in the space of bounded continuous functions.

Comment: @yoyo.Thanks for your attention. Finally, i didn't understand that is it impossible defining an bilinear product in every vector space $V$ over a field $F$ that $V$ be turned into an algebra over $F$ ? Yes or no ? Why and how ?

Comment: @bigli Every vector space is an associative algebra under the product $x\cdot y=0$ for all $x,y\in V$.

Comment: @Burde Thanks. But my mean is : defining a nontrivial (always nonzero) bilinear map as product in $V$ and I have written it in my question.

Comment: @Burde If $x\cdot y=z\not=0$ then $[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x=0$ is as Lie bracket. This structure (Lie algebra) is trivial. What is your idea?

Comment: I meant as a non-associative algebra, not necessarily as a Lie algebra. Just fix any nonzero product on a basis and extend bilinearly (see the comments above).

Comment: @Burde Thanks. I understand exactly  that your bilinear product in every finite vector space $V$, be turned $V$ into an algebra. Now, if $\mathrm{dim}V=\infty$, how is your product?

Comment: @bigli that answer includes the infinite dimensional case. The only issue is if you reject the axiom of choice and your vector space then doesn't have to have a basis.